# How do I show revision users in a view

Tags: views, 6, users, nodes

I would like to create a view that shows the title of all newly revised or updated content with the username of who modified it. The first part is easy, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to show a the username of who updated it as everything shows the original author, not the user who updated the content.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried creating a relationship?

[image]

Sounds like that might give you the data you need, but you'll need to test it out.

Comment: It will work, then add `User: Name` under fields and choose the `user` relationship.

Comment: O ya it really works.

Comment: Yes, this works but if multiple people work together only the last one working on the node will show in the view, not both. What can we do to see who has worked on a particular node?